# Insert data with one SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

I use these tables to store user credentials and roles:

```
CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT(
 ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
 USER_NAME TEXT NOT NULL
)
;     

ALTER TABLE ACCOUNT ADD CONSTRAINT KEY1 PRIMARY KEY (ID)
;    

CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT_ROLE(
 ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
 USER_NAME TEXT NOT NULL
)
;    

CREATE INDEX IX_RELATIONSHIP19 ON ACCOUNT_ROLE (ID)
;

ALTER TABLE ACCOUNT_ROLE ADD CONSTRAINT KEY26 PRIMARY KEY (ID)
;
```

As you can see I use the same ID for the both tables. How I can insert data into these tables with only one SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [with statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/queries-with.html), e.g.:

```
with insert_into_account as (
    insert into account values (1, 'John Doe')
    )
insert into account_role values (1, 'John Doe');
```

Note, that the index `ix_relationship19` is redundant, as primary key creates unique index.

Comment: Traditionally this is done with a few queries in a single transaction. `With` statement is a convenient alternative.